# Efficient date format

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, datetime

What's the most efficient way to do the following date formatting in Python?

```
import re


def f(date):
    month = {"Jan": '01', "Feb": '02', "Mar": '03', "Apr": '04', "May": '05', "Jun": '06',
             "Jul": '07', "Aug": '08', "Sep": '09', "Oct": '10', "Nov": '11', "Dec": '12'}
    d = date.split()
    d[0] = re.match(r'^\d+', d[0]).group(0)
    if len(d[0]) < 2:
        d[0] = f'0{d[0]}'
    d[1] = month[d[1]]

    return '-'.join(d[::-1])


print(f("20th Oct 2052"))
print(f("6th Jun 1933"))
print(f("26th May 1960"))
```

#### Desired Output

```
2052-10-20
1933-06-06
1960-05-26
```

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel - use `datetime` instead.

Comment: @Emma, try this ```from datetime import datetime; datetime.strptime("6th Jun 1933", "%dth %b %Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")```

Comment: @Sushanth It won't work for 3rd May 2020

Comment: @bigbounty, yes this is just an illustration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from dateutil.parser import parse
d=parse("20th Oct 2052")
d1=parse("3rd May 2020")
print(d)
print(d1)
```

Output:

```
datetime.datetime(2052, 10, 20, 0, 0)
datetime.datetime(2020, 5, 3, 0, 0)
```

Using the above datetime you can convert to desired format easily

```
d.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
d1.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

Output:

```
'2052-10-20'
'2020-05-03'
```